# Sumar 4 inputs y mostrar total en otro input JQuery Math

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, math

me gustaría saber cómo Sumar los 4 inputs que ya tengo y mostrar el resultado en otro automáticamente y que a su vez solamente me muestre el resultado con 2 decimales.
¿alguien?

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){    
                $("#modelo").change(function(){
                    var Total;
                    Total=($(this).val()*0.05);
                    $("#riesgo").val(Total);
                });
                $("#modelo").change(function(){
                    var Total;
                    Total=($(this).val()*0.07);
                    $("#cogs").val(Total);
                });
                $("#modelo").change(function(){
                    var Total;
                    Total=($(this).val()*0.4);
                    $("#unitario").val(Total).toFixed(2);
                });
                $("#modelo").change(function(){
                    var Total;
                    Total=($(this).val()*0.4);
                    $("#").val(Total);
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas detectar cuando un input cambia el valor, después recorrer los input obteniendo sus valores (que los irás acumulando) y finalmente usar el `.toFixed()` para decirle que sólo tenga dos decimales.

```js
$('.losInput input').on('change', function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('.losInput input').each(function() {
    if($( this ).val() != "")
    {
      total = total + parseFloat($( this ).val());
    }
  });
  $('.inputTotal input').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
.losInput{
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.inputTotal{
 margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="losInput">
  <label>dato 1 <input type=text /> </label><br>
  <label>dato 2 <input type=text /> </label><br>
  <label>dato 3 <input type=text /> </label><br>
  <label>dato 4 <input type=text /> </label>
</div>
<div class="inputTotal">
  <label>Total </label><input type=text />
</div>
```